# Continuous Interpolation in MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab, input, interpolation, data-analysis

I have a set of data that I would like to get an interpolating function for. MATLAB's interpolating functions seem to only return values at a finer set of discrete points. However, for my purposes, I need to be able to look up the function value for *any* input. What I'm looking for is something like SciPy's "interp1d."

Comment: I'm not really understanding the supposed difference between SciPy's [`interp1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) and MATLAB's [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html). Please provide a [mcve] explaining your issue with it.

Comment: The difference is that MATLAB'S interpolating function has the form:
`vq = interp1(x,v,xq)` 
where x is the table of x values, v is the table of y values, and xq is the finer table of x values that the function is interpolated over.
Scope's function on the other hand has the form:
`vq = interp1d(x,v)`
where x is the table of x values and v is the table of y values. You can then use vq(any_value) to get the value of the interpolating function at any value you wish.

Comment: [interp1 has this syntax](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html#outputarg_pp)

Comment: lol thank u @excaza

Answer (score 2):

That appears to be what [`ppval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ppval.html) is for.  It looks like many of the [1D interpolation functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/1-d-interpolation.html) have a `pp` variant that plugs into this.

**Disclaimer:** I haven't actually tried this.

Comment: See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sco1/c2edee435f83baa6f5183c292263958a) for a MATLAB example.